# Vertica client driver load data to temp table

Tags: temp-tables, vertica

I am using Vertica client driver version 8.1 to save data to temptable using the following query :

```
COPY TempTableName FROM STDIN DIRECT DELIMITER '|' RECORD TERMINATOR '\r\n' NO ESCAPE NO COMMIT;
```

while using this statement to add data to temp table I get a error if I have used "|" in the data to saved.

One of the ways to fix this is using ENCLOSED BY paramater like :

```
COPY TempTableName FROM STDIN DIRECT DELIMITER '|' RECORD TERMINATOR '\r\n' ENCLOSED BY '"' NO ESCAPE NO COMMIT;
```

But in this case if I used " in the data to be saved it leads to an error. This there are a generic way to handle this and insert all possible characters ('",.;/:?~!@#$%^&*|/) on keyboard while saving.

Answer (score 0):

Classical csv issue.

the default parser of Vertica COPY accepts the bar as column delimiter and the bar within strings as a non-delimiter if strings are quoted. And if the quote itself is within the string, the default parser expects it to be escaped by backslash.

So if your table is:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
  id       INT
, fullname VARCHAR(64)
, dob      DATE
);
```

Then, your data file: `bar.csv`, could look like:

```
42|"The Bar \" | \" at the End of the Street"|"1952-02-15"
```

You load it with, for example:

```
marvin ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql
Welcome to vsql, the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal.

Type:  \h or \? for help with vsql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

sbx=> COPY bar FROM LOCAL 'bar.csv' DELIMITER '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' EXCEPTIONS '/dev/tty' REJECTMAX 2;
 Rows Loaded 
-------------
           1
(1 row)

sbx=> -- show the loaded data ...
sbx=> SELECT * FROM bar;
 id |                fullname                |    dob     
----+----------------------------------------+------------
 42 | The Bar " | " at the End of the Street | 1952-02-15
(1 row)

sbx=>
```

Is that the behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: But  in this case if the data itself have \ then it will be used as escape character and will lead to issues. Is there any solution it so that it handle all characters on keyboard like \,|,",' etc.

Comment: If you have the freedom to shape the load file, you have 3 possibilities: 1. escape the quote within quoted strings with the backslash; 2. double the quote within quoted strings, and use PARSER FCSVPARSER() in the COPY command; 3. use ASCII 1 or ASCII 2 for the column delimiter, and use DELIMITER E'\002', for example.

Comment: @coolbuzz The generic solution for this is to use the escape character. You don't really need enclosed by. Any special character should be preceded by the escape character (which is \ by default). If the data itself contains \, it should become \\.